# Hotspot connecting and disconnecting pc

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, linux

Am trying to connect my pc to Android hotspot but it connects and disconnects immediately. My pc os is arch Linux. I have been connecting it before until recently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my PC running Archlinux. I just ran `nmtui` command and was able to connect to hotspot.